# determine the growth rate given a time series data

Tags: regression-coefficients

I have a data sets like this:

```
structure(list(Month = structure(c(14975, 15006, 15034, 15065, 
15095, 15126, 15156, 15187, 15218, 15248, 15279, 15309, 15340, 
15371, 15400, 15431, 15461, 15492, 15522, 15553, 15584, 15614, 
15645, 15675, 15706, 15737, 15765), class = "Date"), TotalLogins = c(284697404L, 
268944957L, 297847827L, 287150001L, 277779620L, 262275285L, 284271058L, 
294965702L, 285132804L, 238847338L, 287527433L, 314483537L, 324823553L, 
322896485L, 329044914L, 318228530L, 324395065L, 324988644L, 335464023L, 
336269471L, 324063033L, 349017727L, 347193478L, 355561387L, 373885187L, 
356774443L, 386372600L)), .Names = c("Month", "TotalLogins"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(11L, 
8L, 18L, 1L, 21L, 16L, 14L, 4L, 27L, 25L, 23L, 6L, 12L, 9L, 19L, 
2L, 22L, 17L, 15L, 5L, 28L, 26L, 24L, 7L, 13L, 10L, 20L))

summary(lm(TotalLogins ~ Month, data=xx))

Call:
lm(formula = TotalLogins ~ Month, data = xx)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-59901492  -4717787   1266082   9432626  26785529 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -1.674e+09  2.121e+08  -7.892 3.01e-08 ***
Month        1.294e+05  1.380e+04   9.377 1.16e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 17020000 on 25 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7786,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7697 
F-statistic: 87.92 on 1 and 25 DF,  p-value: 1.157e-09
```

I am trying to growth of the TotalLogins (coeffient). I dont see this value in the summary. How can I get growth of TotalLogins?

When I do this:

```
lin<-lm(TotalLogins ~ Month, data=xx)
coeff(lin)
```

(Intercept)         Month 
-1673981283.6      129376.3

It is a huge number, does not seem right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

By just looking at your data, the coefficient you've estimated seems consistent with a linear growth trend in time.

The value 129,376 is an associated difference in logins for a one month difference in time. The 95% confidence interval indicates this is consistent with values in the neighborhood of plus/minus 4,000 which indicates strong evidence for growth over time.

The value -1673981283.6 is obtained from grossly extrapolating the expected number of logins at whatever month 0 is found to be, obviously an arbitrary time frame way out of the interval of consideration.

Comment: where do you see the 95% CI? Ok, given those data points, how do I come up with the growth rate?

Comment: You compute the CI or use the `confint` method. I eyeballed it. I interpreted the slope as a growth rate. You haven't specified what growth rate you are trying to measure. I suggest producing a scatterplot and drawing the line of fit from your model.

Comment: how do you calculate the the slop of the line. I thought that was the coefficent.

Comment: The interpretation of an OLS coefficient is a slope. See Kutner, Nachtsheim, Neter, Li "Applied Linear Statistical Models".